# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException where simple array is set

Tags: java, arrays

i have simple Array

```
int[] arr = {-1,-3,-5,12,9,0};
Qs(arr,0,arr.length-1);

private static void Qs(int[] arr,int L,int R) {
         if(L>=R) { 
             return;
         }
         int pivot = partition(arr,L,R);

         Qs(arr,L,pivot-1);
         Qs(arr,pivot+1,R);

    }


 private static int partition(int[] arr,int L,int R) {
        int pivot = arr[R];
        int i = L-1;        
        for(int j=0; j <R-1 ; j++) {
            if(arr[j] < pivot) {
                ++i;
                //swap
                int tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        
        return i+1;
    }
```

and i keep getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:19)
```

which is this in function partition:

```
  int tmp = arr[i];
```

Comment: `int i = L-1;` should be `int i = L;`, and then move `i++` after the swap, and at last, replace `return i+1` with `return i`. See also a pseudo reference implementation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme

Comment: ok it worked but why ? why i can't do L-1 ? if i like to start from -1 ? 
how does it related to the array ?

Comment: Well if you increment `i` in the last iteration of the `for` loop, then its possible that `i == arr.length - 1`, when you now add `1` to that `i` at the end of the method, then you have `i == arr.length` which leads to that exception

Comment: soory you to tell you that this not working allso 
look at this link this exactly what i did 
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/quicksort-in-java/#:~:text=Quicksort%20uses%20a%20divide%2Dand,The%20Easy%20Java%20Training%20Series.

Comment: `arr[j] < pivot` should probably be `arr[j] <= pivot`, also `j = 0` should be `j = L`. And at last you need to swap `arr[i + 1]` with `arr[R]` at the end of the method